# Hibernate OGM & Hibernate OGM first and second level cache

Tags: hibernate-ogm

Will Hibernate OGM supports Cassandra? Since OGM provides JPA support to persist data in NoSQL DBs and it reuses Hibernate core engine, what about first and second level cache? Will OGM supports 1st and 2nd level cache?

Answer (score 2):

Yes supporting Cassandra is on the roadmap; there was an experimental first patch already, but then we stopped evolving it as Cassandra's team was heavily updating their Java client API. Development should resume soon, but we depend on contributors.

[Roadmap for Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/roadmap/)

And yes you can use 2nd level cache as usual: everything except the storage operations are handled by the usual Hibernate ORM code. Of course some concepts might not be available, for example since Cassandra does not support transactions you won't be able to configure a TransactionManager.

Comment: Thanks for the information Sanne. I will followup Hibernate OGM community.